# how to create custom selection of div elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make some divs which I can select.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)

I also want to shift select the divs and multiple dives should only be selected if the user press crontroll (like in a normal windows explorer).

How can I do that?

Comment: sorry i missed the jsfiddle code.... here it is: 
http://jsfiddle.net/3L9y7kre/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

A few years back I tried to make my own tree viewer that allowed fancy selecting features and expanding using divs and CSS. I found it much easier to use the select tag, with the [size attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_size.asp) so it wasn't a dropdown, the [multiple attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp) to give me fancy selecting abilities, and [option groups](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) to denote parent child relationships. Is that an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI library to achieve this quickly and efficiently. It works with CTRL key but not sure about SHIFT key.

Here's the link: http://jqueryui.com/selectable/

Comment: this would be the thing if the user could select multiple options using shift